# An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I am facing a strange exception of type:

> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.PlaybackFailureException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll

Solution is working on development machine but its throwing this exception on deployment machine.I have installed test agent, test controller and visual studio premium 2013 in deployement machine,still facing the same issue

Exception is thrown when trying to Initialize Playback:

> Playback.Initialize()

///Message

> Cannot perform '' on the control. Additional Details: The control
>   details were not specified.

///Stack Trace

> at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException
>   innerException, IPlaybackContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException
>   exception, IPlaybackContext context)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize()    at
>   Test.SAPDupCheck.OpenBrowser() in c:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Test\Test\SAPDupCheck.cs:line 79    at
>   Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\geethu_john02\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 14    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

///Source

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting

///Target Site

> {Void
>   MapAndThrowComException(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.IPlaybackContext)}

///Inner Exception

> {"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {6DA215C2-D80D-42F2-A514-B44A16DCBAAA} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."}

Comment: Is [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be9b6def-f8de-45b3-aecb-291887cd2cb8/mstest-throwing-playbackfailureexception-when-calling-playbackinitialize?forum=vststest) helpful?

Comment: no this is different, if(!Playback.IsInitialized) then only I'm initializing playback

Comment: Please help me in solving this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback version10

dll in my project.

> I have installed visual studio2013 premium which is having 12 version
>   dlls. So the same dll with version 10 was not able to register in the
>   system and the solution is to install `Test agent 2010/Test agent10` and
>   can solve this error.